# Ubuntu running very slow. Unity is being rendered by Intel video card, not by my NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 540M

Tags: 12.04, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04. I have installed bumblebee too, and it works fine. But my operating system is very slow. I suppose it's because the Intel video card is rendering my graphic interface. When I want to use my dedicated video card, I use the optirun command (e.g optirun firefox). How can I use optirun for graphic interface rendering?